# properly handling multi-touch event android

Tags: java, android, multi-touch

I am having trouble implementing multi-touch i have searched for a while. the current implementation works but interrupts other input. this code is part of my input controller which handles/draws input areas. the Motion Event is passed via this function from OnTouchEvent(),
I have read that you must use pointer id to properly keep track, but everytime i try implement it the pointer index is out of range.
i could really use some help

```
 public void handleInput(MotionEvent motionEvent,LevelManager l, SoundManager sound, Viewport vp){
    int pointerCount = motionEvent.getPointerCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++) {
        int x = (int) motionEvent.getX(i);
        int y = (int) motionEvent.getY(i);
        if(l.isPlaying()) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (right.contains(x, y)) {
                        l.player.setPressingRight(true);
                        l.player.setPressingLeft(false);
                    } else if (left.contains(x, y)) {
                        l.player.setPressingLeft(true);
                        l.player.setPressingRight(false);
                    } else if (jump.contains(x, y)) {
                        l.player.startJump(sound);
                    } else if (shoot.contains(x, y)) {
                        if(l.player.pullTrigger()){
                            sound.playSound("shoot");
                        }
                    } else if (pause.contains(x, y)) {
                        l.switchPlayingStatus();

                    }

                    break;


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (right.contains(x, y)) {
                        l.player.setPressingRight(false);
                    } else if (left.contains(x, y)) {
                        l.player.setPressingLeft(false);
                    }


                    break;


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    if (right.contains(x, y)) {
                        l.player.setPressingRight(true);
                        l.player.setPressingLeft(false);
                    } else if (left.contains(x, y)) {
                        l.player.setPressingLeft(true);
                        l.player.setPressingRight(false);
                    } else if (jump.contains(x, y)) {
                        l.player.startJump(sound);
                    } else if (shoot.contains(x, y)) {
                        if(l.player.pullTrigger()){
                            sound.playSound("shoot");
                        }
                    } else if (pause.contains(x, y)) {
                        l.switchPlayingStatus();
                    }
                    break;


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    if (right.contains(x, y)) {
                        l.player.setPressingRight(false);
                    } else if (left.contains(x, y)) {
                        l.player.setPressingLeft(false);
                    } else if (shoot.contains(x, y)) {
                        //Handle shooting here
                    } else if (jump.contains(x, y)) {
                        //Handle more jumping stuff here later
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }else {// Not playing
            //Move the viewport around to explore the map
            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (right.contains(x, y)) {
                        vp.moveViewportRight(l.mapWidth);
                    } else if (left.contains(x, y)) {
                        vp.moveViewportLeft();
                    } else if (jump.contains(x, y)) {
                        vp.moveViewportUp();
                    } else if (shoot.contains(x, y)) {
                        vp.moveViewportDown(l.mapHeight);
                    } else if (pause.contains(x, y)) {
                        l.switchPlayingStatus();
                    }
                    break;
            }



        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i found an answer, using MotionEventCompat i was able to achieve the desired behaviour by adding an index and passing in the event through the MotionEventCompat interface.

```
        int index = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(motionEvent);
        int x = (int) MotionEventCompat.getX(motionEvent, index);
        int y = (int) MotionEventCompat.getY(motionEvent, index);
```

instead of
        `int x = (int) motionEvent.getX(i);
        int y = (int) motionEvent.getY(i);`

right after

```
        for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++) {
```

this seems like such a mistery to me to be honestly it feels really hacky, i'm not even sure if iterating through both pointers is necessary now. i am going to try and comment back

//edit the for loop is for sure redundant, i just had to make sure before i embarrassed myself further

Comment: i was correct, the for loop is now redundant. it feels odd to me but i will go with it,